# Update mysql table using POST

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query:

```
if (isset($_POST['editMessage'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET message = '".htmlspecialchars($editedmessage)."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    if ($result) {
        die("<strong>Message has been edited!</strong>");
    } else {
        die("<strong>Error ".mysql_error()."</strong>");
    }
}
```

Using this form:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
<textarea name='editedmessage' rows='5' cols='70'><?php echo $_POST['editedmessage'];?></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='editMessage' value='Edit'>
```

It's not showing an error, it updates the table field, but doesn't enter the edited message into the field, so the field updates and shows no informtion at all.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is no error. You should show editing lines that generates  $editedmessage var.

Answer (score 2):

```
htmlspecialchars($editedmessage)
```

1. You don't seem to be defining `$editedmessage` anywhere, did you mean `$_POST['message1']`
2. That should really be `mysql_real_escape_string( htmlspecialchars( ... ) )`

Comment: Sorry, I am using $editedmessage = mysql_real_escape_string( htmlspecialchars($_POST['editedmessage']  ) );

Comment: Then you need to be using that variable, your sample code still shows you using $message1 there. PHP will not figure out what you mean, if you are sticking the result in $message1, you need to get it from $message1

Answer (score 1):

Try the other way when its correct you get an ressource back:

```
if(!$result) {
   die('Died: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
   echo "Edited:";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the line:

```
$editedmessage = $_POST['editMessage'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong here

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET message = '".htmlspecialchars($_POST['editedmessage'])."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `$editMessage` in the query instead of _POST[editMessage] (unless you have register globals on, apparently you don't).

However, do NOT do this without running `mysql_real_escape_string()` on editMessage first, and DO NOT run htmlspecialchars() on it! Encoded data does not belong in the DB.

Either do `$editMessage = $_POST['editMessage'];`, or use _POST in the query directly, but wrap it in `mysql_real_escape_string()` for goodness sake!

However, you DO want to run `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()`, or at the very least `string_tags()` on $_POST['message1'] when you echo it out.  This page is XSS (cross-site script) vulnerable.